# Most memory efficient way to remember visited cells in 2d matrix?

Tags: c#, .net, time-complexity, space-complexity

Given a 2d array `int[n,n]`, and given we are implementing some algorithm that requires remembering an arbitrary number of cells (potentially all `n` of them, however on average much lower, see below):

What is the most efficient way we can store the fact we have visited a cell, in the most efficient way possible (least amount of memory) while maintaining constant time lookup?

Let me add another detail:

Worst case is O(n) for quantity of cells we need to remember, **however average case is much lower.** Lets say on average we only need to remember less than O(logn) cells.

I'm interested in optimizing this for the average case.

Comment: To take advantage of your sparseness, perhaps a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) of points, or a `Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>`? Not sure how much memory these actually take up but assuming it's linear in the number of contained elements this should lead to average `O(log n)` space. Profiling for specific use cases etc etc.

Comment: Can you apply an indexing of your own convention where you just keep track of the nth entry? that way your 2 dimensional case reduces to 1 dimension. for example start by counting left to right and row by row, that way for example the cell 2,2 in a 3x3 grid just becomes 5.

Comment: @Arjang That doesn't change the number of indices that can be expressed and so might need to be stored. It's useful, but ultimately equivalent to just using a hash.

Comment: `ulong[]` array, each bit represents 1 cell. Fast and uses not much memory. Of course wrap in in special class.

Comment: @Arjang Yeah that indexing scheme would be valid here

Comment: `HashSet<int>` with the visited cells will probably need a lot more memory for it's internal structures compared to [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray). Depending on the range of the numbers, you can probably do it without any additional memory by using the sign bit or the bit before it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MSB of `int` to use it as a flag for whether the cell was visited or not. If you don't need integers below -2<sup>30</sup> = -1,073,741,824 or above 2<sup>30</sup>-1 = 1,073,741,823 this would be the way to go:

```
public struct TaggableInteger 
{
    private uint _value;

    public bool IsTagged
    {
        get
        {
            return ((this._value >> 31) & 0x1) == 0x1;
        }

        set
        {
            this._value |= value ? (uint)0x1 << 31 : 0;
            this._value &= value ? this._value : (uint)0x7FFFFFFF;
        }
    }

    public int Value 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (int)(this._value << 1) >> 1;
        }

        set 
        {
            this._value = ((uint)value << 1) >> 1;
        }
    }

    public TaggableInteger(int valueInt) 
    {
        uint value = (uint) valueInt;
        this._value = (value << 1) >> 1;
    }
}
```

Test Program:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var i = new TaggableInteger(1047483640);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.IsTagged, i.Value);
    i.IsTagged = true;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.IsTagged, i.Value);
    i.IsTagged = false;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.IsTagged, i.Value);
}
```

Prints

```
False 1047483640
True 1047483640
False 1047483640
```